# Daemon Tools error (0xc0000006)

Tags: windows, daemon

I tried to reinstall Windows XP to Windows 7, but I could not install the video card drivers because the driver installation software only works on XP.
I have launched the setup program with XP mode. After I installed the setup, I restarted the computer and Windows 7 wasn't booting.
But that isn't the problem why I asked this question. The problem is that I have reinstalled my Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows XP SP3 and I wanted to install Dameon Tools.
After installation I restarted the PC (as the setup wanted) and when the Daemon Tools launches it shows the error:

```
Application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000006). Click OK to terminate the application.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download the latest version of Daemon Tools.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people who seem to have this problem have an infected machine. Try using some Malware removal software from safe-mode which may resolve this error. These two are my favourites :

[SpyBot](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/home/index.html)
[SuperAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/)

Answer (score 0):

XP drivers cannot be used in Windows 7 in any way. You have seen the results by losing bootability.

Daemon Tools is compatible with Windows 7 in its more recent versions. Be aware, however, that many have had problems with the DuplexSecure sptd.sys driver. It is possible that it will interfere with hibernation or sleep.

Windows 7 cannot be "installed to Windows XP" nor the opposite, either. I assume that you mean that you have both on the same machine, is that correct?